# Create automatically only getters in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, code-completion

In Eclipse is it possible to create automatically Getters and Setters for a field. But I have a lot of private fields for which only getters should exist. Is somewhere in Eclipse a "create Getters" Function which does not create setters too?

Well, it is not so much work to write getters, but doing it automatically would be nice :)

Thank you,
lerad

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On the `Generate Setters and Getters` screen you have `Select getters` button on the right - use it.

Comment: Worth noting that "Generate Setters and Getters" is available from the "Source" menu, not when clicking "Ctrl+1" with the cursor on the field, which gives the option "Generate getter and setter for 'x'.."

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by automatically? My plugin lets one create fields with Getters or Setters.
You might look into this : http://fast-code.sourceforge.net/. It has simple popup as below:
[image: http://fast-code.sourceforge.net/getter-setter.jpg]
<sub>(source: [sourceforge.net](http://fast-code.sourceforge.net/getter-setter.jpg))</sub>

I should mention that eclipse has create Getters/Setters from the source menu. It also puts a  marker beside any `private member`. Then one just needs to press `Ctrl-1`. Problem with that is it creates both getters or setters.

Answer (score 0):

One more (may be nasty) way of creating *only getters* is:

1. Create the member variables with `final` modifier (such as `private final int hoursSpentInSO`)
2. While in editor, and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd>, <kbd>r</kbd> (*Press the <kbd>r</kbd> key after a slight delay*)
3. You will get only getters for those final fields, press OK
4. Once getters are generated, remove the final modifier (if required)